# Retrieve data from multiple textfields at once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several textfields in my scene which are added programatically according to the user preference. Is there a way to retrieve all textfield data at once and store them in an array corresponding to their order, so from top to bottom the data is added to an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _orderFormArray.count ; i++) {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, x, 70, 20)];
    [textField setPlaceholder:@"Enter Ammount"];
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
    [textField setTag:i];
    [[self view] addSubview:textField];
    textField.delegate = self;
    x+=60;

}
```

My code which adds the UITextFields to the scene, maybe the tag will be of assistance.

Comment: So did you try the solution your question suggests?

Comment: If you looking to get values of all UITextField at one time than you can add the UItextField reference into an array and the you get all value Iterate the Array and retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you question itself is having half of the answer

```
NSMutableDictionary *contentsDic = [NSMutableDictionary array];
for (int i = 0; i < _orderFormArray.count; i++) {
    UITextField *textField = [self.view viewForTag:i];
    [contentsDic setObject:textField.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I nearly got there

Answer (score 0):

You can add the textfield to a mutable array, or you can cycle through the view's subviews:

```
[self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", ((UITextField*)obj).text);
    }
}];
```